# Why opening a pdf from winform I can't highlight text? (normally I can)

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe-reader

When I open a PDF from Adobe Reader (normally) I can highlight text with no problems, but when I open the same pdf file from an Adobe Reader tool into a winform I can't highlight text.

I'm writing in c# VS2015 and here's my code to open the Pdf file into the winform:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf) |*.pdf;";
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (dlg.FileName != null)
        {
            axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(dlg.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Where did I make mistakes? It's a code mistake/forgetfulness or it's a conceptual mistake?

Comment: I don't think the .NET adobe plugin comes default with the option to highlight text, in fact, it might not even have it at all. Check the ax control properties to see if the highlight option is there. Remember, the ax control is a lightweight version of the actual PDF viewer, some features might be disabled

Comment: I checked and.. bad news for me: no possiblity to highlight text. But thank you for suggest me to control the Ax Control properties!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No possibility to do that: suggested by TheDanMan comment I checked the Ax Control Properties and I find out that I can't highlight text (the Ax Control properties are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa845161.aspx)).

Posted this answer for who has problems similar to mine (yes, you can't even take annotations into your pdf with Adobe Reader tool, you've to try another way)